# How to move custompainter based on touch events in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make a timepicker i have made clock design using custom painter in flutter i have also made clock hands using same painting way but now i have no idea how to move them on touch events as one would do to set time.

```
class ClockHandsPainter extends CustomPainter{

 final Offset centerPoint;
 final double radius;
 final int degree;

 ClockHandsPainter( {this.centerPoint, this.radius, this.degree});


 @override
 void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

  var paint = Paint();
  paint.strokeWidth = 2.0;
  paint.color = Colors.white;

  var calculator = Coordinate();

  final Coordinate topPointHourHand = calculator.calculateCoordinate(
    centerX: centerPoint.dx,
    centerY: centerPoint.dy,
    radius: radius,
    theta: degree
  );

  canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(centerPoint.dx, centerPoint.dy),
      Offset(topPointHourHand.dx, topPointHourHand.dy),
      paint
  );
 }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
  return true;
  }

}
```

how will i be able to detect if user has clicked and dragged the clock hand to some point in order to move that hand to that point.

As suggested i tried to make use of GestureDetector but was unable to get any out put from it

```
GestureDetector(
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    size: Size(0.0, 0.0),
                    painter: ClockHandsPainter(
                      radius: clockRadius - 60,
                      degree: 6,
                      centerPoint: Offset(0,190)
                    ),
                  ),
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                  onTap: (){
                    print("tapped");
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: see `GestureDetector` / `Listener` classes

Comment: gesture detector only detects gesture on a widget i want to be able to move the clock hands as the user clicks and drags it to certain position

Comment: i dont know how to make it work

Comment: see `GestureDetector#onPan*` properties

Comment: i am not able to use it with custom paint it yields nothing

Comment: post yur code then

Comment: just did i have edited the question

Comment: and where are your `GestureDetector#onPan*` properties?

Comment: i first tried ontap it didn't yield anything i didnt do anything after that